# token returned is null after addAccount()

Tags: android, accountmanager, android-authenticator

I've been trying to implement an app which saves user accounts (id, password and token) with the Android [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html). Been using [this as my reference](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/) for implementing the functionality.

I am able to show my AuthenticationActivity and create accounts (which show up correctly in the `Settings > Accounts` after I create them). After I add a new account I try to immediately login the user with the token received which I save with `setAuthToken()`. However this never works and I see that the `authToken` is always null. I then have to run the app for a second time and login again after which it works.

The code where I add a new account (from my signup activity) is,

```
private void addNewAccount(final AccountManager am, final String accountType, String authTokenType) {
    Log.d(TAG, "addNewAccount(): " + accountType + ", " + authTokenType);
    am.addAccount(accountType, authTokenType, null, null, this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
        @Override
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
            try {
                Bundle bundle = future.getResult();
                final String authToken = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                Log.d(TAG, "addNewAccount() -> bundle = " + bundle + ", authToken = " + authToken);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
                    startLoggedInActivity(authToken);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "token is null"); // <- always get here
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, null);
}
```

And the code where I finish the login (after I receive the token and add the new user) is,

```
private void finishLogin(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "finishLogin(): " + intent.getExtras());

    if (intent.hasExtra(KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE)) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), intent.getStringExtra(KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
    } else {
        String accountName = intent.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        String accountPassword = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_USER_PASS);
        final Account account = new Account(accountName, intent.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE));

        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(ARG_IS_ADDING_NEW_ACCOUNT, false)) {
            String authtoken = intent.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

            // Creating the account on the device and setting the auth token we got
            // (Not setting the auth token will cause another call to the server to authenticate the user)
            mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, accountPassword, null);
            Log.d(TAG, "finishLogin() -> addAccountExplicitly: " + account + ", " + accountPassword);
            mAccountManager.setAuthToken(account, mAuthTokenType, authtoken);
            Log.d(TAG, "finishLogin() -> setAuthToken: " + authtoken);
        } else {
            mAccountManager.setPassword(account, accountPassword);
            Log.d(TAG, "finishLogin() -> setPassword: " + account + ", " + accountPassword);
        }

        setAccountAuthenticatorResult(intent.getExtras());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    }
    finish();
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be (been struggling with this for quite some time now :( )?

Comment: I have a similar issue, did you ever solve this problem ? When I try to create a new account KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE always returns null. I imagine I will face the same problem as you did when I get past this. Any suggestions ?